# How to disallow spaces in between literals in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

```
grammar = Literal("from") + Literal(":") + Word(alphas)
```

The grammar needs to reject `from : mary` and only accept `from:mary` i.e. without any interleaving spaces. How can I enforce this in pyparsing ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you use `Combine`?

```
grammar = Combine(Literal("from") + Literal(":") + Word(alphas))
```

So then:

*EDIT* in response to your comment.

Really?

```
>>> grammar = pyparsing.Combine(Literal("from") + Literal(":") + Word(pyparsing.alphas))
>>> grammar.parseString('from : mary')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pyparsing.py", line 1076, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ":" (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
>>> grammar.parseString('from:mary')
(['from:mary'], {})
```

Comment: `Combine` does not throw a `ParseException` for `from : mary`. I want the error to be thrown.

Comment: Also, read up on the `leaveWhitespace` method to suppress whitespace-skipping for specific expressions.  Call this method on any expression that must match without skipping spaces, in your case the ':' and the word containing the name.